# How to obtain an array of random numbers having a specific order of magnitude

Tags: matlab, random

For example, let's say I want to obtain `A = [0.0001, 0.0004, 0.0009]` or some other numbers in the order of 10^-4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
rand(1,3) * 1e-4
```

This will produce an array of random numbers uniformly distributed on [0, 1e-4].